# How to apply multiple filters and inputs with ffmpeg

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg

Not only do I have multiple filters, I have multiple inputs that I want to overlay. I usually have to them in 2-3 steps and wonder how to do it all in one command as it should be the most efficient way?

1 and 2 literally identical. For readability, I've cut out the actual filters which are very long and complicated.

1. image slide in left onto video
2. Take output of 1, image slide in right
3. Take output 2, textbox image fade in
4. Take output3, text fade in (finish)

   ```
   1)
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex \
         "[1]scale=640:-1[i0]; \
          [i0]drawbox=color=white:t=15[i1]; \
          [i1]format=,fade=[i2]; \
          [i2]rotate=[i3]; \
          [0][i3]overlay= \
   -c:v libx264 -vb 10M output1.mp4

   2)
   ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -loop 1 -i image2.jpg -filter_complex \
         "[1]scale=[i0]; \
          [i0]drawbox=[i1]; \
          [i1]format=,fade=[i2]; \
          [i2]rotate=[i3]; \
          [0][i3]overlay=" \
   -c:v libx264 -vb 10M output2.mp4

   3)
   ffmpeg -i output2.mp4 -i image3.jpg -filter_complex \
         "[1]scale=1080:-1 [ovrl], \
          [ovrl]format=fade=[i]; \
          [0][i]overlay=" \
   -c:v libx264 -vb 10M output4.mp4


   4)
   ffmpeg -i output4.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=" -vb 10M finaloutput.mp4
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -loop 1 -i image2.jpg -loop 1 -i image3.jpg \
 -filter_complex \
   "[1]scale=640:-1,drawbox=color=white:t=15,format=,fade=,rotate=[i1]; \
    [2]scale=,drawbox=,format=,fade=,rotate=[i2]; \
    [3]scale=1080:-1,format=,fade=[i3]; \
    [0][i1]overlay=shortest=1[o1]; \
    [o1][i2]overlay=shortest=1[o2]; \
    [o2][i3]overlay=shortest=1,drawtext=" \
 -b:v 10M finaloutput.mp4
```

Comment: That's amazing, really concise! However, I'm getting the error "Option loop not found"

Comment: For GIF, `-ignore_loop 0` has to be used in place of `-loop 1` and the GIF must already be set to loop however many times you want.

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't think it was a gif issue because I renamed .gif to .jpg but clearly that doesn't work... Thanks for the help, separate final question if possible. I'm creating 6 of these, all different inputs and joining them together adding an audio track over it all. Can that also be done in one go? Or should I create 6, concat them together, then add audio? What's your advice?

Comment: Can be done in one go. You have to repeat the above filter set, taking care to input the correct images to the filters and assigning unique filter labels. Assign a label e.g. `[f1]` to the final filter output in each set (i.e. after `overlay,drawtext`). After all six are done, use `[f1][f2][f3][f4][f5][f6]concat=n=6`. Add the audio as the last input. If `input.mp4` has no audio, ffmpeg will automatically use the other audio.